# Unable to get the output using regex

Tags: regex, linux, bash

This might be a silly one, but I'm unable to get the required output.

I've a file named `Abc_sfgf_kjwefgk.txt20180929_040845` in a directory.

I'm trying to list the file using the command:
`ls -l Abc_sfgf_kjwefgk.txt[0-9]{8}_[0-9]{4}`

But it's giving me error: `ls: cannot access 'Abc_sfgf_kjwefgk.txt[0-9]{8}_[0-9]{4}': No such file or directory`

While, with this command:`ls -l Abc_sfgf_kjwefgk.txt[0-9]*?_[0-9]*?`

It's giving me the correct result.

What's the problem with my initial command?

Comment: The problem is [globs](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) don't work like regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like everything is okay with your **SECOND** command. Here you correctly use [globbing](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html).

If you want to parse `ls`, then you should use smth like this:

```
ls | grep -E 'Abc_sfgf_kjwefgk.txt[0-9]{8}_[0-9]{4}'
```

Comment: Thanks @Arfeo, i think i was missing `egrep`..uhhh.

Answer (score 1):

`{8}` is a literal string. Since you don't have any file names containing `{` the glob regex `[0-9]` does not expand. Your command is *literally* `ls -l 'Abc_sfgf_kjwefgk.txt[0-9]{8}_[0-9]{4}'`. Since there is no file `Abc_sfgf_kjwefgk.txt[0-9]{8}_[0-9]{4}` you get an error message from `ls`, that there is no such file.

You probably wanted to write

```
ls -l Abc_sfgf_kjwefgk.txt[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]
```

or

```
find -maxdepth 1 -regextype egrep -regex '.*/Abc_sfgf_kjwefgk.txt[0-9]{8}_[0-9]{4}' \
     -exec ls -l {} \;
```

Comment: yeah, i tried the first one : `ls -l Abc_sfgf_kjwefgk.txt[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]`, then of course it seemed too lengthy...i thought there would be some better way to do it ;-).  Thanks for the answer.